# How to create dual boot in my win7 HP laptop

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot

I have HP Pavilion Dv6-3120tx laptop with pre installed windows 7 home basic OS

I have a single 320 GB hard-disk with Windows 7 x64bit pre installed, and the current partition schemes is as follows:

- (c:) === NTFS 277.82GB - Where Windows 7 is installed (Primary)
- HP_TOOLS === FAT32 99 MB
- RECOVERY (D:) === NTFS 19.97 GB
- SYSTEM === NTFS 199 MB

Now i want to create a primary partition by shrinking partition (C:), when i shrink partition
(C:) it will change Basic disk to Dynamic disk...

Plz help me to use multi operating systems in my laptop...

Answer (score 1):

Download [Parted Magic](http://www.partedmagic.com/) and partition your drive before installing the second OS.

Comment: what is this software and how to use this software...? will i lose my current OS and all my personnel data if i use this software...?

Comment: [http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=How+does+Parted+Magic+work%3F+%20Will+I+lose+my+current+OS+and+all+my+personnel+data+if+I+use+it%3F](http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=How+does+Parted+Magic+work%3F+%20Will+I+lose+my+current+OS+and+all+my+personnel+data+if+I+use+it%3F)